# How to enable logging on Business Connector

Tags: 2011

I'm using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 and can't enable the log for Business Connector. I have enabled it in `\Tridion\bc\conf\log4j.properties`, but for some reason file is not created. Here's my log4j.properties:

```
# Set root category priority to ERROR and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootCategory=ALL
log4j.category.com.tridion.integrations.bc=ALL

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=- %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=c:\log\BusinessConnector.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Full pattern
#log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %-30.30c{2} %x - %m %n
# Debug pattern
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Any ideas?

Update: Crashing means that process is crashing
There are no any exceptions in the event log
I have a Visual Studio application and it can connect to BC. It's not that BC is broken completely. Just once in a while it stops

Comment: Why are you using the Business Connector when it has been deprecated? The Business Connector has been replaced with the Core Service. You should really be using the Core Service by now.

Comment: What version of Java are you using and is msvcr71.dll accessible from the system path? http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6509291

Comment: I'm using Java 7 and is msvcr71.dll accessible from the system path. Im interested in the logging part, not debugging part :)

Comment: Is log4j-core.jar in your Classpath?

Comment: Java 7 is not supported with Tridion 2011. Might not be related, but I saw weird stuff happening with this, like transport failing to start.

Comment: I also wasn't able to get it to log to the file specified in log4j.properties. I'd recommend opening a ticket with SDL support.

Comment: Adding to what Nuno wrote, note that there are no plans to support Java 7 in Tridion 2011 SP1. I would recommend to open a ticket with support if you experience the same issue when using a supported platform (one that includes Java 6 for example).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing:

log4j.category.com.tridion.integrations.bc=ALL

to

log4j.category.com.tridion.integrations.bc=ALL,LOGFILE

Comment: That did it for me, great stuff Amit

Comment: Incredible! Thanks, one more thing - path should be of such format: c:\\log\\BusinessConnector.log