# Business Connector logging issue for SDL Tridion 2011SP1HR2

Tags: logging, business-connector

I'm facing a challenge in enabling logging for Business connector in my 2011SP1HR2 environment.

- I have read the post [How to enable logging on Business Connector](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-to-enable-logging-on-business-connector) and made sure log4j config as below:
  log4j.category.com.tridion.integrations.bc=ALL,LOGFILE
- Also i have read another post which was suggesting to install both 32 and 64 bit jre and done that too. [Legacy Business Connector error in Tridion 2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/legacy-business-connector-error-in-tridion-2011)
- Also made sure that msvcr71.dll is placed inside %TRIDION_HOME%\bc\

But after above changes, still business connector is not logging. When i traced the business connector process through "Process Monitor", understood that jvm.dll is not getting loaded.

Could you please suggest what could be causing the issue? Why jvm.dll is not loaded in business connector process?

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Not sure but on the old forum, most of the issues with `jvm.dll` were related to the JRE version or it not being registered correctly. Some fixed by downgrading to JRE 1.5 or having `msvcp71.dll` in `\Windows\System32\`. Any chance you could use the Core Service instead?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have tried both, but still logging is not happening. I think only option is to use core service :(